# How soon can I use 529 for paying college

Tags: united-states, tax-deduction, 529-plan, education-savings, georgia

I enrolled into college. I'm thinking to enroll into 529 plan to pay my college fees for the coming semester. This is with an intent that I will be able to save tax on the money used for tuition.
Is this an option? Can I deposit and withdraw money in 529 in a short timeframe? Please suggest.

Comment: Which state? Each state has their own set of rules regarding state income tax deductions, and minimum amount of time in the program.

Comment: Its for Georgia. I'm planning to do it for the last semester of the program (very later I know).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can deduct up to $4,000 of contributions from your *state* (not federal) taxes in Georgia. So that would save you $230 if you're in the highest Georgia tax bracket (5.75%)

I can't find anything on [their site](https://www.path2college529.com/plan/details.shtml) to indicate how long after a contribution is made before it's eligible for withdrawal, but in my state it's only 7 days.

I would say it's worth a call to see if there's a minimum period before withdrawals are eligible, but you could also pay out of pocket and just "reimburse yourself" later in the year - the funds don't have to go *directly* to the school.

Comment: Thanks for the such a precise detail. I called gapath2college. Hold limit in GA is 8 days. It worked out as I expected.